# How to write a regex that find any values except for those following another regex?

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I have been searching inverse regex and wasn't able to find one.

I have prepared a regex that finds a specific pattern in the table.

**Regex:** `^R([0-9]{3}|[0-9]{4})[-][a-zA-Z]{2,3}[-]([0-9]{5}|[0-9]{4})$`
**Example:** `R788-COV-2040`

Now I want to find all values that do not follow this regex pattern.

Every answer online is about not containing a specific string but not regex.

Comment: Look up "negative lookbehind"

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: on that supr dupr, check answer by @AlanMoore. that is typical and is like mine. the _Accepted_ answer is mostly links that requires hours of investigation but do not directly ansers the question.

Comment: As I understand, you are given a regex that matches one or more substrings of a given string, `s1`, `s2`, `s3`,... and you want to construct a second regex that matches the substrings between `s1` and `s2`, `s2` and `s3` and so on. If that is correct, there is a problem in that no "inverse" regex may exist or there may be more than one that works, in which case I would doubt that one could be derived from the given regex. An analogy from mathematics is that there is no inverse function of `f` when `f(x) = 0` for all `x`.

Answer (score 0):

negate what do not want `^(?!R([0-9]{3,4})-[a-zA-Z]{2,3}-([0-9]{4,5})$).+`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/LerhSI/1)

nate - i facterded yuor regex a bit, good perform now